# Formatting Matlab file with lstlisting

Tags: color, listings, code, sourcecode, matlab

I included a Matlab file, and it worked fine. The colors changed and it looked nice. Suddenly Latex doesn't change the colors of the code, except of the background color. Is something wrong with my code? Or is there a possibility that a included package is disturbing the code?
Thank you very much for answering!

```
\documentclass[12pt, xcolor=dvipsnames]{scrartcl}


\usepackage{listings}
\usepackage[dvipsnames]{xcolor}

\definecolor{codegreen}{rgb}{0,0.6,0}
\definecolor{codegray}{rgb}{0.5,0.5,0.5}
\definecolor{codepurple}{rgb}{0.58,0,0.82}
\definecolor{mygreen}{RGB}{28,172,0} 
\definecolor{mylilas}{RGB}{170,55,241}
\definecolor{backcolour}{rgb}{0.95,0.95,0.92}

\begin{document}

\lstdefinestyle{mystyle}{
    backgroundcolor=\color{backcolour},   
    commentstyle=\color{codegreen},
    keywordstyle=\color{blue},
    numberstyle=\tiny\color{codegray},
    stringstyle=\color{codepurple},
    basicstyle=\ttfamily\scriptsize,
    breakatwhitespace=false,         
    breaklines=true,                 
    captionpos=b,                    
    keepspaces=true,                 
    numbers=left,                    
    numbersep=5pt,                  
    showspaces=false,                
    showstringspaces=false,
    showtabs=false,                  
    tabsize=2,
    aboveskip=\medskipamount
}
\lstset{style=mystyle}

\lstinputlisting{adj.m}
\end{document}
```

[image: PDF Output]

Comment: Welcome to TeX.SX ! Could you include in your question the matlab code, so you can try to reproduce the issue ? Also are you able to go back to the situation where you had colours ?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You haven't provided listings with a language, thus it doesn't know the syntax, and can't colour comments, keywords etc.

If you add `language=MATLAB` to `\lstset`, it should work.

```
\lstset{style=mystyle,language=MATLAB}
```

If you plan on using the same style for more than one language, you can change the language by using `\lstset` again.

You can also specify the language when inserting the code

```
\lstinputlisting[language=MATLAB]{adj.m}
```

Comment: Thank you very much, it solved the problem.